# Embedding C# type library for C++ use

Tags: c#, c++, dll, typelib

I'm writing a program in C++ (unmanaged code) in which I use a C# DLL.

Everything works fine when I'm in a debug mode (the dll is called, the job is done) on my machine 
When I run the debug version of the program on a different server, it won't work too.

Do I have to embbed my TLB library in the .exe? If so how to do that?

However, when I "release" it the program act wierdly.

Comment: When you build for release, does it work on the remote server?

Comment: Please add a comment of why you downvote a question. Especialy when it's new person. Perhaps they will understand why you downvote them...

Comment: - The IDE is Visual Studio 2008
- When i build for release, it won't work even on my local machine

Answer (score 0):

C++ is compiled instead of interperted like C#. So you probably have to recompile your program on the other server.

Comment: There is not another way to do it ? Do i have to recompile it on every machine ?

Comment: If this was indeed the problem (have you tried recompiling?), you have to recompile the source code for at least every machine with different specifications. That's the disadvantage of compiled languages. Here is [a page](http://www.vanguardsw.com/dphelp4/dph00296.htm) that briefly explains the difference.